# Go: "embedded type cannot be a type parameter"

Tags: go, generics

I was writing a type safe wrapper over "request-response"-style goroutines using Go generics and stumbled upon a compile error:

```golang
type WorkerContext[In any, Out any] interface {
    Process(In) (Out, bool)
    Destroy()
}

type Worker[In any, Out any] struct {
    context WorkerContext[In, Out]
    in      chan In
    out     chan struct{Out; bool}
}
```

Here, a goroutine is represented by a `Worker` instance, and the user code that is executed within the goroutine to handle requests is represented by a `WorkerContext` interface (which may potentially hold arbitrary external resources, such as a child process that the goroutine is communicating with).

The idea here is that the `WorkerContext.Process()` function returns the result of processing a request, and a flag indicating if the external resource can accept more requests. Both values are transmitted via the channel back to the requesting thread. There, the flag is used to decide whether to put the worker (with its associated goroutine and the context) back into the worker pool or destroy it (creating a new one when the next request comes up).

However, I can't seem to declare such a channel:

```
chan struct{Out; bool}
```

It gives this error:

```
src/taskpool/taskpool.go:24:22: embedded field type cannot be a (pointer to a) type parameter
```

---

Why is that so? The restriction feels kinda arbitrary, and what is the idiomatic way to do what I want to do here?

Comment: Do you have to have Out be embedded? Why not `struct{Out Out; bool}` for example? I'm not on Go's design team, so I don't know why they disallow it. I can imagine a reason or two, but ultimately it's just not allowed by the language.

Comment: I'm case you're not familiar with the terminology: the embedded field is the "unnamed" Out type, which would mean you can reference Out's fields as if they had been inlined into the enclosing struct. You can't do that on a generic parameter type; but your can always just give it an explicit field name, and then it'll work.

Comment: @yshavit I was trying to use a struct with embedded fields as a poor-man's tuple. I think I tried naming the fields before asking and it failed to compile for some reason, but I think it was an unrelated syntax error or somesuch, because I tried that again and yes, it worked.

Still, I wonder what is the reason for this restriction.